# How to do arbitrary non-negative powered polynomial division in Mathematica?

Tags: polynomials

Suppose I have a simple polynomial in $\{a,b\}$, defined as $a^k-b^k \ \forall \ k\in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq0}$. If I know one of the factor is $(a-b)$, is  there a way to get a representation of its remaining factors in Wolfram Language?

I know one of its representation is $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}{(a^{(k-1)-j}\ b^j)}$ and Mathematica recognizes that

```
Sum[a^((k-1)-j) b^j,{j,0,k-1}]
```

gives

```
(a^k - b^k)/(a - b)
```

But if I ask

```
FullSimplify[(a^k-b^k)/(a-b),Assumptions->k\[Element]NonNegativeIntegers]
```

It is unable to do anything.

Also what is the proper way to give assumptions?

Is the above expression intepreted differently if I give as

```
Assuming[k\[Element]NonNegativeIntegers,FullSimplify[(a^k-b^k)/(a-b)]]
```

Also tried factoring directly without giving a single factor to no success,

```
Assuming[k\[Element]NonNegativeIntegers,Factor[a^k-b^k]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that $x^k - 1$ factors into the cyclotomic polynomials of the divisors of $k$. To factor $a^k - b^k$ instead, we take the cyclotomic polynomials in $a/b$ and remove the denominator.

For Mathematica to give you a general expression in `k`, it would have to generate an infinite product of `(...)^Boole[Divides[k, d]]` terms, or quantify over the `Divisors`, which seems beyond what [Factor](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factor.html) is capable of (all the documentation examples result in polynomial expressions).

```
factorDiffOfPows[k_Integer] :=  (Expand[Numerator@Together@Cyclotomic[#, a/b]])& /@ Divisors@k

Print[factorDiffOfPows@10]
Print[AllTrue[Range@105, Expand[Times @@ factorDiffOfPows@#] == a^# - b^#&]]
(*
{a - b, a + b, a^4 + a^3*b + a^2*b^2 + a*b^3 + b^4, a^4 - a^3*b + a^2*b^2 - a*b^3 + b^4}
True
*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY09C8IwFEX3/ooHgaJQqQ4uQiFiHVy0SLeQyrOmNbRJJEn9@PWxQydd773nHoX@LhR6WWMIDdbe2Fw2zakpzMux7nLQXrTCcthkALP9@4H6xo6DEhbHKS1NK8YDS3efujfeKFkzkgCmV87nMaQUcvmUzlhHuygqrNSe/Vroasmnatv3pR0EO6NuxZivE5iUpVTCAaXwRxMOWQZYEVjAtSIx5yF8AQ)